# scheduling a bat file which uses rclone

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, rclone

I made a .BAT file which looks like this:

```
cd "C:\Portable Apps\rclone"
rclone mount Test: X:
```

What this does is mount a cloud storage location to my "X" drive. When I am double clicking this batch file everything works properly, but when I try to launch it through windows task scheduler nothing happens.

Note: I also tried to use a `.EXE` wrapper using a utility called "bat2exe", but nothing seems to work.

What did I do wrong...help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try generating error log for rclone line. also have you permitted administrator privilege to task scheduler

Comment: i did grant it admin rights...as far as log file goes I couldnt figure out how to generate one.

Answer (score 2):

I SOLVED IT

Made a batch file with following:

```
cd "C:\Portable Apps\rclone"

rclone mount Test: X: --config C:\Users\MyUsername\.config\rclone\rclone.conf
```

Then I entered the following settings in windows scheduler:

[image]

Executed it and Behold it worked :))